# Remove "unset" from terminal prompt

Tags: linux, bash, debian, raspberry-pi, unset

I was editing my .bashrc in my raspberry pi home directory, and now terminal prompt is stuck as follows:

```
[pi@hostname ~]$ unset
```

I can't delete unset from the prompt. What did I do, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Could you give us your .bashrc file ? And the result of `env` ?

Comment: what's in your `PS1`? (what's the output of: `echo $PS1`?)

Comment: \[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\][\u@\h \W]\$ unset

Comment: I've removed unset, which solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely caused by the command being on the same line as your PS1 variable.

Just find the line where you set your PS1 variable and move unset down one line.

That should fix your issue.